# Ellipsize text inside TextView instead of clipping

Tags: android, android-layout

In my `ListView` row I have title and subtitle. If title takes two lines I'd like the subtitle `TextView` to shrink and text inside to be ellipsized to fit the remaining space. Title should have priority over subtitle. How do I prevent subtitle to get clipped?

[image]

Here s the row:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:background="#FFF">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/news_unread_indicator"
        android:layout_width="5dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@color/unread_news" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp">


        <com.gigaset.elements.ui.custom.CheckBoxMuseo
            android:id="@+id/news_delete_chckbox"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <com.gigaset.elements.ui.custom.TextViewMuseo
            android:id="@+id/news_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/news_delete_chckbox"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:textColor="@color/text"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <com.gigaset.elements.ui.custom.TextViewMuseo
            android:id="@+id/news_description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/news_title"
            android:layout_below="@id/news_title"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="2"
            android:textColor="@color/newsfeed_news_subtitle"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The problem is not with the ellipsize. You just set a fixed height to your relative layout that's why it is cutting your text. Why not changing that to wrap_content, you already set the max lines to 2?

Comment: @orelzion The row has to be fixed size. Sometimes title would have 1 line and subtitle 2 lines and sometimes title would have 2 lines and subtitle 1 line. It is the number of lines in the title that defines the number of lines in subtitle.